# Compile part of all dependencies as shared libraries

Tags: haskell, dll, shared-libraries, haskell-stack

Say I got (regular source) libraries `A` and `B` and executable `E` which depends on both.

Now, I want `E` to include the object files of `A` directly, whereas `B` should be added as a shared library (concrete use: `B` contains shared types of a plugin architecture). How would I do that with existing tools, preferably `stack`?

Is that possible or is it rather an all-or-nothing choice (use only shared libraries or link everything into the same binary)?

---

Optimally, I'd like to specify for each dependency if it should be linked statically or dynamically. Also, that should probably go into the `.cabal` file, but we have to work with what we got...

(Well, technically that's both statically linked, but in the second case the object code is split up in different files, you get the idea).